# tail -n equivalent for X last chars of a file?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I'm searching a way to display X last chars of afile.

I've a big log file with everything on 1 line... I'm just interested for the last chars of this log.

I didn't found anything to solve my problem.

Comment: Erm what's unclear about the documentation for tail ?

Comment: I had not seen the -c parameter. Thank you to forwarded me in the right way. I don't think the downvote was required, anyway thanks. My problem is now solved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From `man tail`:

> ```
>    -c, --bytes=K
>           output the last K bytes; alternatively, use -c +K to output bytes starting with the Kth of each file
> ```

Comment: wow... I had not seen this parameter in the man. I read it to quickly I think. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: ...and here I was just about to submit an answer using sed. I should probably stop seeing regex solutions everywhere :)